# Xamarin Forms (Xaml) ListView not displaying images

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

My XAML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="MyApp.Mobile.MyPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="http://MyUrl/MyImage.png" />  <!-- WORKS -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding RowName}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ColumnName}" />
                            <Image Source="http://MyUrl/MyImage.png" /> <!-- DOES NOT WORK-->
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Xamarin Forms (testing on Android)
The first image displays fine.  The very same image in the ListView does not display.
Ultimately I will using a Binding like the Labels (which work), but I have hard coded the URL as I diagnose the issue.

Does anyone know why the Image is not displaying in the ListView?

Comment: Have you tried setting `HasUnevenRows="True"` on ListView?

Comment: Use `FFImageLoading` for this!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below,

```
<ListView 
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding RowName}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ColumnName}" />
                            <Image Source="http://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/index/hero.jpg" />
                            <!-- DOES NOT WORK-->
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

It is working checked at my end.

Happy Coding..

Kishore Kumar Vangala.

Comment: I am confused.  It works with your image but not with mine!!  Maybe jpg vs png?

Comment: I have no idea, spent hours on this.  Your example worked, put it back to my image and that worked too!?!?  OK... on to the next problem...

Comment: Please make it as an answer if it solves your issue, it may useful for others @RobL

Comment: @RobL Please mark it as answer if it was useful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I higly suggest to use **FFImageLoading** when dealing with images in listview.
The performance gain and optimized memory consumption is **huge!**
[Github](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) | [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms)

Then in listview, in order to avoid issues with cell sizing, is better to specify `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` to your `Image`, then use an `Aspect` that fits your need (`AspectFit`, `AspectFill`, ecc...)

Just tested now and everything is working without issues.